# Azure Active Directory

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

I am developing a suite of applications that will be hosted in Azure.  Some apps will be for customer use (not public tho, i.e. invited/paid up customers) and some for internal employees.

For authentication I was initially going to use something like the excellent ThinkTecture IdentityServer.  This would allow me to define claims to partition different user types (i.e. a 'HasAccessToAppX' claim or 'IsCustomer' claim).   However to save having to develop/maintain and deploy another application, I was considering using Azure Active Directory (NOT the Azure AD B2C which seems to be targeted at public facing consumers/social logins etc).  The problem I have is that I want to have single sign on and claims based authentication, but I cannot figure out if its possible to assign custom claims for user sets.

It appears there is group management facilities, but they seem to cost a fortune!

Am I looking at the right technology here to achieve this?  Or is my approach fundamentally flawed?

Comment: Is there anything your specialized tin is going to be doing that can't be done with [OpenId](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/)?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, but do you mean OpenId as a protocol.  Or do you mean OpenId as in work with an external OpenId identity server i.e. google etc?

Comment: So I guess the approach I have settled on is to use Azure AD for now, but only for Authentication via OpenId (it means if I need other protocols - SAML/ws-fed etc down the line they should be supported - dont know if this is really a consideration).

I will maintain user details (modeled as identities and claims with claim values) in a separate DB and on successful authentication of the user, I will make a call to retrieve the user data.  It means if I swap out the AD bit in the future, I still own the user data.

Comment: You can manage groups of users in azure AD and then configure AAD to send a user's groups as claims when they log in.

Comment: See [how do I ask a good question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).